# Swig to java, typedef enum does not create enum type in java class

Tags: java, c++, enums, swig, typedef

I am working on my first swig project, with a 3rd party library which is very old.

There is a mix of proper enums and the typedef enums declared, and swig does what i expect it to do with enums where it translates the enum props with values to java, but with the typedef enums it only translates it to an int.

example.h

```
typedef enum
{
   prop1 = data,
   prop2
} enumName;
```

file.i

```
%module example

%include "enums.swg"
%javaconst(1);

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%include "example.h
```

How can i add the enum values to the generated java interface?

Edit 1.

Adding the typedef enum directly in the interface file generates the java file correctly with enum definetion.
But is this the correct approach ? it seems like this will require alot of maintenance during third party project update.

new file.i

```
%module example

%include "enums.swg"
%javaconst(1);

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

typedef enum
{
   prop1 = data,
   prop2
} enumName;

%include "example.h
```

Edit 2:

The %ignore "" and %rename("%s) is also in effect and this seems to be the culprit.

Doing the same approach on a different file without ignore will create proper wrappers.

Edit 3:

The %ignore was indeed the culprit.

And %rename("%s") enumName; is not sufficient to unignore the properties in the enum.

Answer (score 0):

The %ignore was indeed the culprit.

And `%rename("%s") enumName;` is not sufficient to unignore the properties in the enum.